# How to avoid flyway package conflict in spring-boot-starter-parent and dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, flyway

folks. My situation is described as below:

- I have a maven application and a library that is used to help initialize datasource and free my app from datasource handling.
- The library injects beans to application and needs to call flyway.migrate() in it.
- I want to maintain flyway version ONLY in the library.
- My app POM:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.11.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
```

The problem i met is:

If I declare flyway as dependency only in library but not in app, when app is running, flyway.migrate() in library finds the Flyway in `<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>` of my app ( yes there is a flyway imported from `spring-boot-starter-parent`) which has a lower version. Then I will have to declare flyway as dependency in both app and library which is hard to maintain.

My plans are:

- Find a way to exclude Flyway in `spring-boot-starter-parent` then hopefully it can find the correct flyway. But i did not find a way to do it yet.
- Or try to somehow override the flyway version by the library. but still no finding yet.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Most of the Spring Boot dependency versions are property-based. Try setting `flyway.version` in your project POM as a Maven property.

Comment: Hey, good point! It makes it running. But the remaining problem is that i  cannot maintain Flyway version in library but only in the app. I tried to set this property in library but it will still follow the app's flyway version. I am thinking if it is because i did a Bean injection in library, so even through the codes are in library but they actually run in the app. @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-